# Is it possible to get a timestamp without invoking an external command like `date`?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tcsh

zsh builtin `print` has option `-P` to perform prompt expansion, and this could be used to get the current time. I wonder if there are other ways to achieve this? And how about for other shells?

Comment: Do you mean, time from timestamp?

Comment: yes, but there seems no other way but invoke external command, are there?

Comment: Don't know what the other guys are talking about here. You don't know a way doesn't mean there isn't a way. Sure there is. `zmodload zsh/datetime && print $EPOCHSECONDS`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 : I took my answer back thank you for ponting that out. I did have a look  `strftime` but i never knew that it is incorporated to newer bash shells.

Comment: @sjsam No problem, I also didn't know that until several weeks ago. Sorry about my strong words, but I was slightly annoyed by the obnoxious atmosphere in this question. Seeking a native solution seems legit to me.

Comment: If you want a single approach portable between all the tagged shells, then you're going to be disappointed. Both bash and zsh can do this (I don't know about tcsh -- but don't use it, anyhow), but there's no such capability specified in POSIX sh, so you won't find a solution portable across all available shells.

Answer (score 7):

`bash` 4.2 introduced a new format specifier for the `printf` builtin. With no argument, it prints the current time in the given format.

```
# Default is the current time
$ printf "%()T\n"
8:30 
# Current year
$ printf "%(%Y)T\n"
2015
```

An integer argument is treated as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

```
$ printf "%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n" 1234567890
2009-02-13
```

The same works in (some versions of) `ksh`, from which `bash` presumably borrowed it.